# how to find "wx" module version from erlang shell?

Tags: erlang

I use module_info() as follows, the vsn field doesn't contain the version information. How to translate `190640877967407394157636569138961474448` to wx version?

From erlang 24.3.3,
wxErlang Reference Manual
wx Version should be 2.1.3.

```
(chair@macbook.local)1> wx:module_info().
[{module,wx},
 {exports,[{parent_class,1},
           {new,0},
           {new,1},
           {destroy,0},
           {get_env,0},
           {set_env,1},
           {subscribe_events,0},
           {null,0},
           {is_null,1},
           {equal,2},
           {getObjectType,1},
           {typeCast,2},
           {batch,1},
           {foreach,2},
           {map,2},
           {foldl,3},
           {foldr,3},
           {create_memory,1},
           {get_memory_bin,1},
           {retain_memory,1},
           {release_memory,1},
           {debug,1},
           {demo,0},
           {module_info,...},
           {...}]},
 {attributes,[{vsn,[190640877967407394157636569138961474448]}]},
 {compile,[{version,"8.0.3"},
           {options,[debug_info,
                     {d,'USE_ESOCK',true},
                     {i,"/buildroot/otp/lib/wx/src/../include"},
                     warn_unused_vars]},
           {source,"/buildroot/otp/lib/wx/src/wx.erl"}]},
 {md5,<<143,108,24,249,12,71,11,187,138,125,241,49,52,90,
        99,144>>}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
1> application:load(wx).
ok
2> application:loaded_applications().
[{kernel,"ERTS  CXC 138 10","8.3.1"},
 {wx,"Yet another graphics system","2.1.2"},
 {stdlib,"ERTS  CXC 138 10","3.17.1"}]
```